# how to stop non-null filter affect when you select from another filter?

Tags: filter, tableau-desktop, tableau-cloud

I am having difficulties with the Tableau in terms of filter context. I have a table like this:

| Shop Type | Profit | Revenue Plan |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Online | 10 | 15 |
| Store | 20 |  |
| Popup | 30 | 10 |

So in this worksheet, I have a filter for Revenue Plan (Measure)to show only non-null values, which is already applied to this worksheet. So it is empty for Store but since there is Profit, it is showing the Store row. But if I select Store from the Shop Type filter, It is not showing any row.

So the desired outcome to show Store when this filter is applied. Is there a simple way to fix this behaviour? Because complex solutions can cause some problems for Business Users.

Comment: Your question is still a little unclear. Explain your filters in more detail, or post an example to Tableau Public, or run the describe worksheet menu command to give more info. Otherwise, its hard to know what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think everything in your question is entirely correct. In my own opinion, if you have applied a filter at the worksheet level (or at any level by the way) that excludes null values for **Revenue Plan** you should not be able to see the row of **Shop Type**=Store, even if it has **Profit**.

Anyway, if I correctly understand your question, I think that you can achieve the desired behavior of the dashboard by adding a calculated field named (for example) **Profit & Revenue**

```
IFNULL([Profit]) AND IFNULL([Revenue Plan])
```

then adding to the filters and exluding only True values.